# Fast rising to slow rising Integer interpolation

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I want to rotate a panel in my JFrame.
At the moment it is roatating constant because I always add 1 degree to the actual angle.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
{
     Thread.sleep(15);
     panel.rotate(i); // this rotates to the angle (i)
}
```

But what I want is a fast rising Integer, which gets slower, when the value gets higher.
For example the Integer starts at 0 and ends at 360.

*Example Image:*
[image: Example Image]

And how do I put all the values in one Array?

Comment: The simplest option would be to change sleep time in each iteration.

Comment: "And how do I put all the values in one Array?" - no idea what this is supposed to mean and what it has to do with the main problem.

Comment: You could also create a function that translates each timing step to an angle. If plotted, that function would look like your image.

Comment: For example the Array got a length from 100.
What I want is to calculate the Integers between Array = {0, ..., ..., ..., ..., 360};